# addclass() working in console but not working in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a div dynamically. tried to add class as expanded through `jquery` its not working. But i tried the code in console, its working fine there.

code are follows:

appending element name

```
var menuId= '#itemMenu' + indexOfElement;
```

and then tried this

```
$(menuId).addClass('expanded');
```

when i tried folllowing in console

e.g.     `$('#itemMenu5').addClass('expanded')`

its working fine..

Comment: Please show a fiddle. The code looks fine, the problem must be somewhere else

Comment: Yah, @Flixer is right

Comment: What does indexOfElement show in console?

Comment: the same code is working is reused for other codes already present. its working fine their also

Comment: Did you check the value indexOfElement ? Is is '5' when you're trying to add a class?

Comment: value is passing fine

Comment: your code looks fine, Did you get any error in console ?

Comment: @PandiyanCool We need to see more code to accurately solve your problem. How are the DIVs being created dynamically? Where is `indexOfElement` being set?

Comment: @AfromanJ indexOfElement is just number which represent number of current span element

Comment: @PandiyanCool i think the code you displayed works fine. please check [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6mNW/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var menuId= 'itemMenu' + indexOfElement;
var element = document.getElementById(menuId);
element.className += ' expanded';   //note the space
```

Comment: `getElementById` Only takes an ID. So the hash sign isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the dynamic DIV using this example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="static">I am static</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.expanded {
    font-size: 20px;   
}
.never-added {
    color: red;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
var indexOfElement = 5;
var menuId = '#itemMenu' + indexOfElement;

//store the new DIV in a var
var newDiv = $('<div/>').text('I am dynamic').attr('id', menuId);
newDiv.insertAfter('#static');

//add the class later
newDiv.addClass('expanded');

//never added
$('#itemMenu5').addClass('never-added');
```

**[Here is a Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skd4a/1/)**

Creating a DIV dynamically then tring to apply a class to it using the ID you assigned i.e `$('#itemMenu5').addClass('expanded');` won't work as the DOM does not know about the new element yet.

Assigning the new element to a variable will allow you to modify it.

**EDIT:** 
I have added an example that shows a class of `never-added` which never gets aded to the new DIV.

Comment: how to assign the created div to a variable? other than this? var newDiv = $('<div/>').text('I am dynamic').attr('id', menuId);

Comment: This will also work `var newDiv = $('<div id="'+ menuId +'">I am dynamic</div>');`. How are you currently creating the DIV?

Answer (score 0):

You might try with:

```
$("#menuId").addClass('expanded');  try directly
```

Comment: have ou included jquery file  or writing the  code in $(ducument).ready function()  {    });